# Get Specified element in array of json - SPLUNK

Tags: javascript, json, analytics, splunk

I im newbie in splunk.
I have this json:

```
"request": {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "x-real-ip",
            "value": "10.31.68.186"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-forwarded-for",
            "value": "10.31.68.186"
        },
        {
            "name": "x-nginx-proxy",
            "value": "true"
        }
```

I need to pick a value when the property name has "x-real-ip" value.

Comment: Are you using the splunk search tool, or something outside of their gui interface?

Comment: this question really shouldn't be downvoted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this - here's the one I use most often (presuming you *also* want the `value` along side the `name`):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp request.headers{}.name="x-real-ip"
| eval combined=mvzip(request.headers{}.name,request.headers{}.value,"|")
| mvexpand combined
| search combined="x-real-ip*"
```

This skips all events that don't have "`x-real-ip`" somewhere in the `request.headers{}.name` multivalue field

Next, it combines the two multivalue fields (name & value) into a single mv field, separated by the `|` character

Then expand the resultset so you're looking at one line at a time

Finally, you look for *only* results that have the value "`x-real-ip`" in them

If you'd like to then extract the `value` from the combined field, add the following line:

```
| rex field-combined "\|(?<x_real_ip>.+)"
```

And, of course, you can do whatever other SPL operations on your data you wish

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Warren's answer but I got the following error:

> Error in 'eval' command: The expression is malformed. Expected ).

You need to add a rename because the `{}` charcters in `mvzip` causes problems.
This is the query that works:

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp request.headers{}.name="x-real-ip"
| rename request.headers{}.name AS headerName, request.headers{}.value AS headerValue 
| eval reviewers=mvzip(headerName,headerValue ,"|")
| mvexpand reviewers
| search reviewers="x-real-ip*"
```

Comment: When I ran this the `combined`  field could not be found.

Answer (score -2):

```
your search
| rex max_match=0 "name\":\s\"(?<fieldname>[^\"]+)"
| rex max_match=0 "value\":\s\"(?<fieldvalue>[^\"]+)"
| eval tmp=mvzip(fieldname,fieldvalue,"=")
| rename tmp as _raw
| kv
| fields - _* field*
```

When you ask a question, please present the correct information.
You've run out of logs in the process.

Comment: why are you rex'ing out fieldnames when Splunk has already parsed the JSON into its requisite key-value pairs?

Comment: hi @warren

`when Splunk has already parsed the JSON`

Really? 
With this questioner's information, we don't know that.

That's why I used `rex`.

Comment: yes, we do know that. Splunk parses JSON when it receives it: it's a native data format :)